# How AdMob identifies that it is a test device or real user?

Tags: android, admob

I am creating an app with AdMob ads, and I have provided my test device id so that my account is not banned.

But when I am finished developing, I want to install the real app on the same device and use it as a normal user would.

Is my device still supposed to be a test device?

How does google identify that it is a test device? I guess it should be looking for the debug or release flavor of the app to decide this, but I just want to be sure.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

When running your App in Debug mode, you should get the following message in your logcat:

```
I/Ads: Use AdRequest.Builder.addTestDevice("XXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXXX") to get test ads on this device.
```

This is exactly the code you have to use to add a test device. 
In Release mode, simply remove this line of code (or change it depending on product flavor) to get real ads.

But most likely you will test your app in release mode on the same device, too. So maybe it is a bad idea to remove your test device from the admob list of test devices.

Comment: Well this is the real question, that in release mode would google think that the device is a test device still and it is being used for tampering, even if it is not.

Comment: How could I check if correct live ads are showing up on my device if I put the device as test even in the release mode?

Comment: Upload your apk to Play Store and put in alpha, have someone you know with Android Phone download and let him/her tell you if real ads are showing up. But honestly, if you're seeing Test Ads, your application will show real ads. Test Ads and Real Ads are pulled from the web.

Comment: @Jörn : is it confirmed if I leave my addTestDevice id in my release app, then my  account activity won't be marked as suspicious?

Answer (score 0):

For Testing purpose you will add below lines.

```
.addTestDevice(AdRequest.DEVICE_ID_EMULATOR)        // All emulators

.addTestDevice("AC98C820A50B4AD8A2106EDE96FB87D4")  // An example devic ID
```

If you remove .addTestDevice() This will be treated as a live Device.

For more information look at this url:

https://developers.google.com/admob/android/targeting#test_ads